# Why is my AmazonCredentials object invalid?

Tags: ios, core-data, amazon-web-services

I'm testing out backing Core Data onto DynamoDB and I have implemented `AWSPersistenceDynamoDBIncrementalStoreDelegate` on my app delegate, with the pertinent `credentials` method implemented as such:

```
- (AmazonCredentials *)credentials
{
    if(credentials==nil) {
        credentials = [[AmazonCredentials alloc] initWithAccessKey:@"ACCESS_KEY" withSecretKey:@"SECRET_KEY"];
    }
    return credentials;
}
```

obviously substituting my real security credentials as appropriate (this isn't how it would be implemented for production, but I don't want to setup a TVM for the prototyping I'm doing).

However, when I attempt to create an `Entity` as such:

```
Track *track = (Track*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Track" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];
```

I get the following error:

```
error: Error Domain=com.amazonaws.coredata.AWSPersistenceDynamoDBClientErrorDomain Code=-1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.coredata.AWSPersistenceDynamoDBClientErrorDomain error -1.)" UserInfo=0xa5363d0 {message=The protocol - (AmazonCredentials *)credentials didn't return a valid AmazonCredentials object.}
```

I can see that the `AmazonCredentials` object is instantiated and has the correct details and I can use the same credentials to establish an `AmazonS3Client` session and download files from a bucket, so they are definitely valid.

Has anyone seen this / know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, looking at the code on Github https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/src-persistence/AWSPersistenceDynamoDBIncrementalStore.m it shows that you have to use the three arg constructor including a security token to use DynamoDB to back Core Data, would be useful if in mentioned that in the docs, but anyway, in short you have to implement a TVM to be able to do this.

Comment: Having looked in to setting up a TVM I realised (as Bob has also pointed out) that STS was made available to the iOS SDK last year however, pretty much all the AWS documentation still refers to using TVM, I have therefore added a quick write up on how I got this working http://codeghost.co.uk/blog/2013/1/15/authenticating-against-aws-with-sts

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that currently the DynamoDB client requires session credentials, these can be provided by the Secure Token Service (STS) client and not require a TVM to be implemented.

[STS Client for iOS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient.html)

Comment: Thanks Bob, yes I realised that when I started looking into the TVM, it's very badly documented on AWS with all the docs I looked at still pointing towards TVM so I actually wrote up how I got STS working. I've added a comment to my original answer with a link if you're interested.